# Can I get my folder back after running git commit but not push?

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, git-commit

So I created a folder and created some files inside it.Now
I ran

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "some message"
```

and now if I deleted the folder can I get it back

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the folder in which you ran `git init`, NO. After `git init`, an invisible folder `.git` is created. The files and non-empty subfolders that you later add and commit are converted to git metadata and stored in `.git`. If `.git` is removed (when you remove its parent folder), the metadata of versions are gone. If they are not pushed or copied or exported or archived as a backup, they are lost.

If you remove the committed files or subfolders except `.git` before you make new changes to them, yes, you can recover them. It's one of the basic functions of a version control system.

If the committed files are modified again, and you remove them before `git add` or `git commit` or `git stash` or copied to somewhere else, the modified versions are gone too, because they don't have a chance to be converted to metadata.

Comment: I am new to this. Thanks for the details.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which folder have you removed. If it was new added subfolder which was committed earlier, than just restore it from your local repo. Execute command:

```
git reset --hard
```

And your local changes would be restored

In other case, if you have removed external directory which contained your `.git` subfolder without sending commit on remote server - than you lost your changes, because you have initialized you git repo locally, have been working with it and eventually removed it

Comment: This will also remove uncommitted changes

Comment: Yes, of course `git reset --hard` will remove all uncommitted changes